# Unable to drop Mongodb index in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

How can a collection's index be dropped from a Meteor server?

```
Games._dropIndex()
Games._ensureIndex({
    name: 'text', 
    description: 'text'
})
```

This gives an error `MongoError: invalid index name spec`

Answer (score 2):

The **[error](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.upgradeCheckAllDBs/#index-specification-invalid)** you are getting is as a result of not supplying the [**`dropIndex()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) method with the parameter of the index you are trying to remove.

To resolve, specify the index to **[drop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/#db.collection.dropIndex)** as the parameter. You can specify the index either by the index name or by the index specification document.

You can also use the [**`db.collection.dropIndexes()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dropIndexes/#dropindexes) command to **[remove all indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-indexes/#remove-all-indexes)**, except for the `_id` index from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Add `_1` to index name:

`Games._dropIndex('test_1')`